# Subtyping of Prop in Coq. Implementation of Ackermann class theory. First-order theories.

Tags: logic, computer-science, foundations, computer-assisted-proofs, alternative-set-theories

I am trying to implement [Ackermann set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_set_theory).

The first approach is the code below.
But there is an incorrect axiom "rs_ax".
That's because for every x formula (F x) shouldn't contain predicate M. $\big((\mbox{M}\ x)\leftrightarrow (x\in\mbox{V})\big)$

1) Is it possible to define a subtype L of Prop, such that its elements are constructed without predicate M? (I am afraid that it is highly likely impossible.)

The second approach of implementing Ackermann set theory is to implement predicate logic syntactically. (re-invent the definition of formulas, substitution, etc)

2) Did you used such syntactic libraries? Could you provide some links or references?

Maybe there are other approaches?

`Require Export Setoid.
Module Type ACK_sig.
Parameter
 (class : Type)
 (M : class -> Prop) (* is_set *)
 (eq_class : class -> class -> Prop)
 (in_class : class -> class -> Prop).
 Notation "x \in y" := (in_class x y) (at level 60).
 Notation "x == y" := (eq_class x y) (at level 70).
Parameter
 (eq_class_ax : forall a b, a == b <-> (forall x, x \in a <-> x \in b)).
Parameter
 (cc_ax : forall (F: class -> Prop), 
(forall y, F y -> M y) -> (exists x, forall y, y \in x <-> F y)).
 (rs_ax : forall (F: class -> Prop), 
(forall y, F y -> M y) -> (exists x, (M x) /\ forall y, y \in x <-> F y)).`

Comment: (Theoretical) Computer Science SE seems more appropriate place to ask your question.

Comment: There are 207 questions on CS.SE, 185 on Math.SE and 3,772 questions about Coq on StackOverflow. I think, the last fits better. Unfortunally, I can't move it by myself. Or shall I delete and re-create?

Comment: Not necessary. You need not remove your question, but post it on other site. There are many cross-posted questions over various SE sites.